# How to run a function over all the values of a column/variable for multiple columns/variables

Tags: r

I'm new to R so grateful if someone could help me here, because I've now tried a lot of things myself that have been unsuccessful and I'm so frustrated!

I have a big dataset that I have manipulated into two types of dataframe layouts where the variables of interest (A, B, C...) are either unique rows or unique columns. (A, B, C...) are categorical, and their values are integers.

```
LAYOUT 1<br>
A, 1, 6, 11...<br>
B, 2, 7, 12...<br>
C, 3, 8, 13...<br>
D, 4, 9, 14...<br>
E, 5, 10, 15...<br>
```

```
LAYOUT 2<br>
A, B, C, D, E...<br>
1, 2, 3, 4, 5...<br>
6, 7, 8, 9, 10...<br>
11, 12, 13, 14, 15...<br>
```

I want to run a number of math functions like mean() over each variable (A, B, C..) and record the outcomes in new dataframe that shows the outcomes of this function against each variable.

i.e.

```
X, mean_X, mode_X, sd_X...<br>
A, mean(A), mode(A), sd(A)...<br>
B, mean(B), mode(B), sd(B)...<br>
C, mean(C), mode(C), sd(C)...<br>
D, mean(D), mode(D), sd(D)...<br>
E, mean(E), mode(E), sd(E)...<br>
```

However, because the dataset is big, I can't do this manually by selecting each variable. I can't figure out how to do this on either of the layouts.

Happy which ever layout you choose, but is there a way to do this simply, preferably just using base, `dplyr`, `tidyr`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you are looking for `apply()`

```
A=c(1, 6, 11)
B=c(2, 7, 12)
C=c(3, 8, 13)
D=c(4, 9, 14)

df<-cbind.data.frame(A,B,C,D)


df$mean<-apply(df, 1, mean) # 1 is applying the function along rows, 2 along columns
df$sum<-apply(df, 1, sum)

df

   A  B  C  D mean  sum
1  1  2  3  4  2.5 12.5
2  6  7  8  9  7.5 37.5
3 11 12 13 14 12.5 62.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in long format so that it is easier to apply multiple functions.

If you have Layout 1 like this :

```
layout1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), V2 = 1:5, V3 = 6:10, 
    V4 = 11:15), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

layout1

#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  A  1  6 11
#2  B  2  7 12
#3  C  3  8 13
#4  D  4  9 14
#5  E  5 10 15
```

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

layout1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric)) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), 
            sd = sd(value), 
            sum = sum(value))

#  V1     mean    sd   sum
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1 A         6     5    18
#2 B         7     5    21
#3 C         8     5    24
#4 D         9     5    27
#5 E        10     5    30
```

---

If you have data in the form of layout 2

```
layout2 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 6L, 11L), B = c(2L, 7L, 12L), C = c(3L, 
8L, 13L), D = c(4L, 9L, 14L), E = c(5L, 10L, 15L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

layout2

#   A  B  C  D  E
#1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  6  7  8  9 10
#3 11 12 13 14 15
```

You can apply the functions using `across` :

```
layout2 %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), 
            list(mean = mean, sd = sd, sum = sum), .names = '{col}_{fn}')) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c('X', '.value'),
               names_sep = '_')

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  X      mean    sd   sum
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1 A         6     5    18
#2 B         7     5    21
#3 C         8     5    24
#4 D         9     5    27
#5 E        10     5    30
```